Migrate Postgre DB to a higher version server remote server (eg. 13 to 15)
I have copied a database from source server (Postgres 13) to target server (Postgres 15) with the well-known commands run on the target server:
pg_dump -h 192.168.8.2 -p 5433 -U postgres -d db -f db.sql
psql -U postgres -d db -f db.sql > db.log

During the process I have encountered neither errors nor warnings.
Now, if my application uses the source server, everything is fine as it was, but as soon as we connect it to the new one, we get at least one SQL-Related error:
2024-04-17 12:40:41.701 CEST [246485] postgres@db FEHLER:  Müll folgt auf Parameter bei »$3O« bei Zeichen 1892
2024-04-17 12:40:41.701 CEST [246485] postgres@db ANWEISUNG:  SELECT o.id AS orderitems_id,
                   c1.accno AS inventory_accno, c1.new_chart_id AS inventory_new_chart, date('10.01.2024') - c1.valid_from as inventory_valid,
                   c2.accno AS income_accno,    c2.new_chart_id AS income_new_chart,    date('10.01.2024') - c2.valid_from as income_valid,
                   c3.accno AS expense_accno,   c3.new_chart_id AS expense_new_chart,   date('10.01.2024') - c3.valid_from as expense_valid,
                   oe.ordnumber AS ordnumber_oe, oe.transdate AS transdate_oe, oe.cusordnumber AS cusordnumber_oe,
                   p.partnumber, p.part_type, p.listprice, o.description, o.qty,
                   p.classification_id,
                   o.sellprice, o.parts_id AS id, o.unit, o.discount, p.notes AS partnotes, p.part_type,
                   o.reqdate, o.project_id, o.serialnumber, o.ship, o.lastcost,
                   o.ordnumber, o.transdate, o.cusordnumber, o.subtotal, o.longdescription,
                   o.price_factor_id, o.price_factor, o.marge_price_factor, o.active_price_source, o.active_discount_source,
                   pr.projectnumber, p.formel,
                   pg.partsgroup, o.pricegroup_id, (SELECT pricegroup FROM pricegroup WHERE id=o.pricegroup_id) as pricegroup
                 FROM orderitems o
                 JOIN parts p ON (o.parts_id = p.id)
                 JOIN oe ON (o.trans_id = oe.id)
                 LEFT JOIN chart c1 ON ((SELECT inventory_accno_id                   FROM buchungsgruppen WHERE id=p.buchungsgruppen_id) = c1.id)
                 LEFT JOIN chart c2 ON ((SELECT tc.income_accno_id  FROM taxzone_charts tc WHERE tc.taxzone_id = $1 and tc.buchungsgruppen_id = p.buchungsgruppen_id) = c2.id)
                 LEFT JOIN chart c3 ON ((SELECT tc.expense_accno_id FROM taxzone_charts tc WHERE tc.taxzone_id = $2 and tc.buchungsgruppen_id = p.buchungsgruppen_id) = c3.id)
                 LEFT JOIN project pr ON (o.project_id = pr.id)
                 LEFT JOIN partsgroup pg ON (p.partsgroup_id = pg.id) WHERE o.trans_id = $3ORDER BY o.trans_id, o.position

As we see, something is wrong at "$3ORDER BY", as if a whitespace was missing. I suppose something is wrong with the data on the new server, maybe some stored procedure or a similar thing was copied with error.
The question is, what is the right way to migrate data to another server with higher Postgres major version?

(a) Locate that code in the sql dump-file, then (b) check exactly what character-codes are in the dump file and (c) what is in the old database. If you cannot find it in the sql then the query is coming from your application code.

It looks like an error in the application

This is not an issue with the data as you have not gotten to the part where the data is retrieved. It is an issue with the statement formatting on the part of the client. I'm guessing Postgres tightened up it's parsing rules from 13 --> 15 and it not allowing this through any more.

You are right, the application developers say it is a known problem in that application version that we use.
